# What is the best practice for naming collections within a library in .Net?

Tags: .net, collections, shared-libraries, naming-conventions

So, I'm building a library in VB.Net and I'm finding the using Collections seems to fit the bill.  Pulling from my VB days, it was common the find a plural name of an object when referencing an array or collection.  For example you have an object `Dog`, and often times would also have a collection `Dogs` which would have it's own class and methods for adding and removing `Dog` objects.

Extending this a bit, say if I had a class `Kennel` and contained a public object `Dogs`, what should I name the instantiated object?

```
Class Dog

End Class

Class Dogs
    Inherits System.Collections.CollectionBase

    Public Sub Add(ByVal value As Dog)

    End Sub
End

Class Kennel
    Public Dogs as Dogs
End
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Dogs` is good based on this criteria: If I read `Dogs` and saw it used `Dogs.Add(dog)`, `For Each dog in Dogs` I would intuitively assume that it was a collection of `Dog`. That's what matters. Can someone (including yourself) easily read it and understand it?

If you're only inheriting from `CollectionBase` and just need a collection then `List(of Dog)` or `Dog()` would also very clear.

Comment: Would anybody find `Public Dogs as Dogs` offensive?